# Impala variables and session id with JDBC

Tags: jdbc, impala

In impala-shell I can define variables and get the session id with the profile command. I'm looking for similar functionality using a JDBC connection. Is this limited to the shell or is there any way to achieve this with JDBC?

**Update**

When I run the 'profile' command from the shell I get a report like this:

```
Query Runtime Profile:
Query (id=4c47466abb90bda5:8f0e5aa3ee01c7a6):
  Summary:
    Session ID: d34f51a1b95852fa:d83aa5e8911f96ab
    Session Type: BEESWAX
```

I'm interested in how to get the 'Session ID' with JDBC.

For the variable substitution, I know I could do a custom version of it from Java but unfortunately we use a 3rd party tool which connects with JDBC and I'm looking for a built in solution to store some information in a variable which attached to the session.

Comment: Variable substitution is done by the command interpreter inside the shell *(along with stripping comments, detecting command separators, etc.)*; then the final commands are submitted, one by one, to Impala. You can re-develop your own command interpreter with Java code, or use astandard JDBC `PreparedStatement`. Have fun!

Comment: The `profile` shell command is defined as _"Prints the runtime profile of the last DML statement or SELECT query executed."_  So what do you mean by "session ID"? Is that the result of `pid()` Impala function, e.g. `select pid() ;`? Cf. https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_misc_functions.html

Comment: I updated the question. @SamsonScharfrichter

Comment: _"I'm looking for a built in solution"_ -- built in what? Impala has no "procedural" extension of any kind, it processes only basic SQL commands; so that leaves only your JDBC client >> _"we use a 3rd party tool"_ -- so, does that tool support custom variable substitution?